# how set field app-version in helm3 chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I udgrade my spring application in k8s use helm. I have default chart and use command

```
upgrade my-app my-app-chart --atomic --set image.tag=123
```

in dir my-app-chart i have file Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
name: my-app-chart
description: A Helm chart for spring application my-app-chart
version: "1"
appVersion: "{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
```

i expect that helm evaluate field appVersion and in helm history i see 123, but now i see

```
C:\git\ci\top-ci-example-project-multi-module>helm history -n top-ci my-app
REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                  APP VERSION             DESCRIPTION

150             Wed Nov  3 00:30:09 2021        superseded      my-app-chart-0.1.0     0.1.0                   Rollback to 148

151             Wed Nov  3 00:38:38 2021        failed          my-app-chart-1         {{ .Values.image.tag }} Upgrade "top-ci-example-mul
ti-module-one" failed: timed out waiting for the condition
152             Wed Nov  3 00:38:49 2021        deployed        my-app-chart-0.1.0     0.1.0                   Rollback to 150
```

how set field appVersion correctly?

Answer (score 8):

`Chart.yaml` & `values.yaml` are not parsed as templates.
c.f. https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#templates-and-values -

> All template files are stored in a chart's templates/ folder. When Helm renders the charts, it will pass every file in that directory through the template engine.

`Chart.yaml` & `values.yaml` are explicitly ***not*** in that directory by design, and so cannot have templating actions (`{{...}}`) usefully embedded in them.

Accordingly, while you *can* supply an appVersion in `Chart.yaml` which will act as a fallback/default base value, [appVersion](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-appversion-field) is only used (in the default charts generated by `helm create foo`) once, in `templates/deployment.yaml` -

```
image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
```

(Interesting to note it is used as `AppVersion` with a capital A, but listed in `Chart.yaml` as `appVersion` with a lowercase A.)

Of course, you could just use `sed` to edit the chart at runtime, but then you have to download and unwrap the package first, which opens another can of worms. Don't do that if you can avoid it - and since you appear able to edit the chart, you *can* avoid it.

According to the docs,

> This field is informational, and has no impact on chart version calculations.

and is, in fact [***entirely optional***](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file) -

> appVersion: The version of the app that this contains ***(optional)***. Needn't be SemVer. Quotes recommended.

So, my recommendation is to entirely remove it. Do NOT rely on it at all.
If you have a sane default that's ok anywhere, set it in `values.yaml`, though it's better to *leave it blank* and require it [be set at deployment](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing) with `--set` statements and/or a `--values` file.

The chart doesn't need to change from deployment to deployment unless the model itself needs to be refactored...assuming you have it in a properly formatted repo.

```
helm upgrade "$name" "$chartRepo/$appName"
```

or perhaps more likely (with variables set at runtime) something like

```
helm upgrade -i -n "$targetEnv" "$appName" "$chartRepo/$appName" \
   --set "image.repository=$dockerRepo/$appName,image.tag=$appVersion"
```

or

```
helm upgrade -i -n "$targetEnv" "$appName" "$chartRepo/$appName" -f run.yaml
```

(I know that seems obvious, but I'm seeing a lot of people hardcoding `appVersion` into charts for *every* release of the app and pinning the chart version to the app release version, even though the chart hasn't otherwise changed.)

Summarizing - "how set field app-version in helm3 chart?"

Don't. [Use run-time values.](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have template in `Chart.yaml` afaik, seems like you are doing this in reverse.

We use [helm-gradle plugin](https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-gradle-plugin) and there, it is very easy to say that "chart version is project version" via its `expansions`:

```
// expansions are replaced in the chart files if found in the form ${path.to.value}
expansions = [
        helm: [
                chartName:'my-chart',
                chartVersion: project.version
        ],
        anotherParam: project.version,
        path: [
                to: [
                        value: 'foobar'
                ]
        ]
]
```

And in `Chart.yaml`:

```
appVersion: ${helm.chartVersion}
```

In projects that use `maven`, the same plugin for maven does not support this extensions future, but it is trivial to do that with a different maven plugin.

This is also trivial to do with `sed` (or any other tool to replace text in a file *before* you build the chart), and this is what we used to do before we introduced this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the version number of the application being deployed. This version number should be incremented each time you make changes to the application. Versions are not expected to follow Semantic Versioning. They should reflect the version the application is using.

The above is the content of the official document, you can initialize a chart project through helm, and then see it in `Chart.yaml`

Comment: yes, i initialize it, you can see it on 5 line in my example Chart.yaml.
My problem is that it doesn't change! I deploy application with tag 123 and expect that app version will be 123

Comment: Tag is generated automatically. And I don’t want to change something manual in the Chart file with each deployment.

Comment: Versions are NOT expected to follow Semantic Versioning.

Comment: what does semantic versioning have to do with it?

Comment: 123 is example version. It is not 1.2.3